# Problema al agregar fila a datatable con los atributos de un archivo

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, fileupload, upload

Tengo el siguiente código html:

```
<div id="divCreaPDF" class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label>Imagenes:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <table id="mTabla-imagenes" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" style="width: 100%">
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="row">
            <label for="btnAgregarArchivoImg" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar</label>
            <input type="file" name="btnAgregarArchivoImg" id="btnAgregarArchivoImg" style="display: none"/>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <input type="button" id="btnQuitarImg" name="btnQuitarImg" value="Quitar" class="btn btn-primary"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Y el siguiente javascript:

```
function creaTablaReorder(idTabla,arrayDatos,columnas,defColumnas,idiomaDataTable,funcionComplete,columnaReorder){
    if ($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable(idTabla)){
        var table = $(idTabla).DataTable( );
        table.destroy();
        $(idTabla).empty();
    }
    let tabla=$(idTabla).DataTable({
        "destroy": true,
        "data":arrayDatos,
        "columns": columnas,
        "columnDefs": defColumnas,                     
        "language": idiomaDataTable,
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": false,
        "scrollY": "425px",
        "sScrollX": "100%",
        "scrollX": true,
        "rowReorder": true,
        "rowReorder": {
            "dataSrc": columnaReorder,
        },
        "select": true,
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "paging": false,
        "ordering": false,
        "info": false,
        "initComplete":function(setting, json){funcionComplete(setting,json);}
    });
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        tabla.columns.adjust().draw();
    }, 700);
}
let columnasImagenes=[
            {"data":"tamano",className:"reorder",class:"reorder text-right",render:$.fn.dataTable.render.number(',','.',0,'')},
            {"data":"nombre",class:"left"}
        ];
        let columnasDefsImagenes=[
            {"targets": -1, className: "dt-head-center"},//todas las columnas
            {"targets": 0, "title": "Tamaño"},
            {"targets": 1, "title": "Archivo"}
        ];
        let arrayDatos=["",""];
        arrayDatos.push({size:333,name:"dgdsg"});
        arrayDatos.push({size:111,name:"ooo"});
        arrayDatos.push({size:222,name:"uuuu"});
        funcionAlCompletarImg=function(setting,json,datosJson){
            let tablaImg = $("#mTabla-imagenes").DataTable();
            $("#mTabla-imagenes tbody").on("click","tr", function () {
                if ($(this).hasClass("selected")){
                    $(this).removeClass("selected");
                    $("#btnQuitarImg").hide();
                }else{
                    tablaImg.$("tr.selected").removeClass("selected");
                    $(this).addClass('selected');
                    $("#btnQuitarImg").show();
                }
            } );
            
        };
        creaTablaReorder("#mTabla-imagenes",null,columnasImagenes,columnasDefsImagenes,lenguajeGeneralDataTable,funcionAlCompletarImg,"size");
```

Y el problema lo tengo en la siguiente funcion:

```
$("#btnAgregarArchivoImg").on("change", function(){ 
        let archivo=$("#btnAgregarArchivoImg").prop("files")[0];
        console.log(archivo);
        if(!(archivo==""||archivo==null||archivo==undefined)){
            let tablaImg = $("#mTabla-imagenes").DataTable();
            let tamano=archivo["size"];
            let nombre=archivo["name"];
            console.log(nombre);
            console.log(tamano);
            tablaImg.row.add([tamano,nombre]).draw(false);
        }
    });
```

Me sale el siguiente mensaje de error:

> DataTables warning: table id=mTabla-imagenes - Requested unknown
> parameter 'tamano' for row 0, column 0. For more information about
> this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

Lo que busco es mostrarle al usuario solo los campos `nombre` y `tamano` para que el archivo que me dio el `input type="file"` vaya como una columna oculta. Leyendo dicha pagina entiendo que el problema es porque no puede leer la variable `tamano` al renderizar el `datatable` para agregar un fila con los atributos del archivo. Pero por mas que he leído y releído dicha pagina no logro dar con el problema.
Al final busco que esta linea `tablaImg.row.add([tamano,nombre]).draw(false);` quede de la siguiente manera `tablaImg.row.add([tamano,nombre,archivo]).draw(false);`.
¿Alguien que me diga que estoy haciendo mal? Nota: Los console.log si me imprimen los datos del archivo.

Comment: "", null y undefined son falsy. if( archivo ), if ( !!archivo )

Comment: Entiendo el comentario, lo que no entiendo es porque dos `!!`, no seria solo uno???

Comment: La doble negación se utiliza para convertir un objeto a booleano direcamente.

obj = { name: 'Diego' }, console.log( !!obj ) // true

Comment: gracias, no sabia eso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error te lo genera dado que tu defines las columnas a tu Datatable en base  un objeto, y por lo tanto cuando añades un registro espera un objeto con esas propiedades, y al buscar esas propiedades en un arreglo que es como se lo proporcionas no localiza las columnas.
Lo que espera es un objeto de el tipo `{tamano:0, nombre: 'algo'}`.

Te dejo el código con el único movimiento que realice, al agregar el row, enviarlo en la forma que lo espera.

```js
$("#btnAgregarArchivoImg").on("change", function () {
        let archivo = $("#btnAgregarArchivoImg").prop("files")[0];
        console.log(archivo);
        if (!(archivo == "" || archivo == null || archivo == undefined)) {
            let tablaImg = $("#mTabla-imagenes").DataTable();
            let tamano = archivo["size"];
            let nombre = archivo["name"];
            console.log(nombre);
            console.log(tamano);
            tablaImg.row.add({ tamano: tamano, nombre: nombre }).draw(false);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   $("#btnAgregarArchivoImg").on("change", function(){ 
        const archivo=$("#btnAgregarArchivoImg").prop("files")[0];

        if( !!archivo ){
            const tablaImg = $("#mTabla-imagenes").DataTable();
            const tamano=archivo.size;
            const nombre=archivo.name;
            console.log(nombre, tamano);
            tablaImg.row.add([
              ''+(tamano/1024).toFixed(2),
              nombre
            ]).draw(false);
        }
    });
```

Haz la prueba, ahora.

Comment: He probado esto y no funciona, básicamente creo que no cambio nada porque `tamano` trae un entero y `''+(tamano/1024).toFixed(2)` sigue siendo un entero, gracias por el intento. Obtengo el mismo error.

Comment: Me refería a cambiarlo a string, aparte de que son bytes. String(tamano)

Comment: Si, ya he intentado como entero y como string, siento que tiene algo que ver con que al inicio la tabla esta vacía y no conoce los tipos de las columnas, por eso hasta puse el render `render:$.fn.dataTable.render.number(',','.',0,'')`, luego hice esto `String(tamano)` sin y con el render, pero todo culmina en el mismo error.